# "Error writing minivpn binary " when connection to open vpn Android

Tags: android, vpn

i know this question asked before several times, but i am facing the issue with this. i have downloaded the code from github from this [link](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn). 
i have successfully imported code into Android Studio. and it is compiling but when i click to connect openvpn then i am getting some errors that are : 
Failed getting assets for archicture x86, Failed getting assets for archicture armeabi-v7a, Failed getting assets for architure armeabi and Error writing minivpn binary.
I am attaching the screenshots of my problem, please see them and assist me , i will be very highly thankful to you.
Thanks in Advance..!

[image]
 In this above screen shot i have successfully imported ovpn file from my sd card.

[image]

after that it ask for user name and password, I entered user name and password then i am getting some error to connect with VPN, that are showing in the given screen shot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution myself with the help of Schwabe(Owner of this code,Thank you Schwabe) of this problem, i am not deleting this question may be it help to others, In my code problem is that i was doing wrong with jniLibs path into my gradle file. It should be like this.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'ovpnlibs/assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['lib']
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build
    }

    ovpn3 {

    }

    debug {

    }

    release {

    }
}
```

and structure should be like this:

```
ovpnlibs
ovpnlibs/assets
ovpnlibs/assets/nopie_openvpn.arm64-v8a
ovpnlibs/assets/nopie_openvpn.armeabi
ovpnlibs/assets/nopie_openvpn.armeabi-v7a
ovpnlibs/assets/nopie_openvpn.mips
ovpnlibs/assets/nopie_openvpn.x86
ovpnlibs/assets/nopie_openvpn.x86_64
ovpnlibs/assets/pie_openvpn.arm64-v8a
ovpnlibs/assets/pie_openvpn.armeabi
ovpnlibs/assets/pie_openvpn.armeabi-v7a
ovpnlibs/assets/pie_openvpn.mips
ovpnlibs/assets/pie_openvpn.x86
ovpnlibs/assets/pie_openvpn.x86_64
ovpnlibs/jniLibs
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/arm64-v8a
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libjbcrypto.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopenvpn.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libopvpnutil.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/armeabi
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/armeabi/libjbcrypto.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/armeabi/libopenvpn.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/armeabi/libopvpnutil.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libjbcrypto.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libopenvpn.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libopvpnutil.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/mips
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/mips/libjbcrypto.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/mips/libopenvpn.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/mips/libopvpnutil.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/x86
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/x86/libjbcrypto.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/x86/libopenvpn.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/x86/libopvpnutil.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/x86_64
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/x86_64/libjbcrypto.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/x86_64/libopenvpn.so
ovpnlibs/jniLibs/x86_64/libopvpnutil.so
```

Comment: @ Amit , I'm facing same issue in VPN. and As you mention the link in question . I don't get any minivpn file in the asset folder. Can you please share any link for the code .